# how to repeat the animation in jquery

Tags: jquery

i am playing with the animate of jquery
here's what i have

```
     $('p:first').animate({
    'paddingLeft':'+=300px','opacity':'-=1' 
     },10000,'swing',function(){
     $(this).fadeOut('fast',function(){
         $('<p>test</p>').insertBefore($('p#2nd'));
     });
 });
```

now , my question is, how to repeat the same animate action on the inserterd

after the fadeOut effect ?, or, there's a better way to do this ?

Comment: But... if you do this you will end in an infinite loop!

Comment: Have you tried setInterval? Just set it for every 100-500 ms or so and you won't have issues blocking (hanging the browser). In the setInterval, call your animate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/2DKA9/2

  `startClouds()` is called recursively until there are no more paragraphs.

```
function startClouds(i) {
  var lmargin = Math.round(Math.random() * 20) + '%',
      tmargin = Math.round(Math.random() * 20) + '%', 
      par = jQuery('p');

  if (i < par.length) {    
    par.eq(i).addClass('cloud')
      .css('left', lmargin)
      .css('top',  tmargin)
      .fadeIn(1000)
      .animate({'marginLeft' : '+=50%', 'opacity' : '-=.93'}, 4000)
      .fadeOut(1000, function () {
        startClouds(i += 1);            
      });       
    return true;       
  }  
  return false;
}

jQuery(function () {
  startClouds(0);
});
```

Comment: You mean animate first paragraph, insert, then animate first paragraph, insert...?

Comment: yeah, something like that, i want it repeat endlessly, behaves like the old marquee ?

Comment: actually, the reason am asking for it , is because am planning to build my own personal site, and add clouds on it that passes by and fade endlessly at the header, with the effect am trying to play with, can you help me sir?